# HTML/CSS: Font does not render vertically centered with inline-block

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following HTML/CSS code:

```css
p {
  background: lightgray;
}

p#h {
  height: 1em;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5em;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<p>Ay<span></span></p>
<p id="h">Ay<span></span></p>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlRep.jpg)

https://jsfiddle.net/e82gzayt/2/

How to get the inline-block having the same height as its parent?

or

How to get the font to be centered vertically with the span block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex value to center vertically. Advanced css class.

Try this

```css
p { display:flex;align-items:center;background: lightgray; height: 2em;}
p#h { display:flex;align-items:center;height: 1em; }
span { display: inline-block; margin-left: .5em; height: 1em; width: 1em; background: red; }
```

```html
<p>Ay<span></span></p>
<p id="h">Ay<span></span></p>
```

Comment: That's it. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You should add that text inside span to be inline. Also, in second case you are restricting the height of p element to be 1 em.

```css
p {
  background: lightgray;
}

p#h {
  height: 1em;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: .5em;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p><span>Ay</span></p>
<p id="h"><span>Ay</span></p>
```

Check the first element. It is aligned fine now.

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/e82gzayt/3/

EDIT: Removing the height and width restriction of span the text fits well inside the p block.

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/e82gzayt/4/

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem. I need an inline-block after the text of same height and width as the height of the text. https://jsfiddle.net/e82gzayt/7/

Comment: @MichaSch : Well. that was not clearly mentioned in the original post. Anyways, it seems like you got your answer with the flex-box.  :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` and then wrap the two `<p>` tags in a `<div>` like this:

```css
p#h { height: 2em; }
span { 
display: inline-block;
margin-left: .5em; 
height: 1em; 
width: 1em;
background: red;

}

.vertical-center {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  width: 400px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="vertical-center">
<p>Ay<span></span></p>
<p id="h">Ay<span></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try with flex box

```
p { background: lightgray; 
display:flex;
  align-items: center;
}
p#h { height: 1em; }
span { display: inline-block; margin-left: .5em; height: 1em; width: 1em; background: red; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e82gzayt/5/

Comment: Can you add a snippet to prove your solution?